# Should I rate limit my API based on IP or JWT token?

Tags: api, jwt

I'm implementing rate limiting on my API. I can customize which key it will use to limit the calls. My software is an SaaS web app for companies, so I think using the rate limiting key by IP address might be bad, since I might have clients that have multiple users and make multiple calls from the same IP. So my next option would be using the JWT token itself to throttle the calls (it is renewed every 5 minutes). Even though it seems like a good option to me, I've found it's not very popular, as a (quick) research about it didn't bring any results of people using it.

Are there any drawbacks to using JWT token as an API rate limiting key?

Comment: Do you remember what you ended up doing? Curious about your findings!

Answer (score 3):

Try decoding the JWT and using the user ID, if it's stored in there.

You'll have a truly unique identifier that doesn't go away when a user switches IP addresses, coordinates from multiple points, or renews their authentication lease.

Comment: Do you still think that's a good approach? Not judging, I just trully want to learn from your experience!